# Item not displaying in spinner once selected

Tags: java, json, android-studio, spinner

I am having a problem where the data that I have from my ArrayList are not displaying when I am putting through my spinner. The data was originally JSON, that I put into the ArrayList. The data displays fine in the drop-down menu, however, once it is selected, it does not appear on the spinner screen. Any help on how to fix that? In java

Thank you!

```html
ArrayList<Service> list = new ArrayList<>;

public void setUpSpinner(){
Spinner services =  findViewById(R.id.servicesSpinner);


ArrayAdapter<Service> servicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Service>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, list);
    servicesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    servicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    services.setAdapter(servicesAdapter);
  } 
  
  
// THIS IS WHERE I INPUT DATA INSIDE LIST

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    /**
     * Getting JSON Object from Web Using okHttp
     */
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParser.getDataFromWeb();

    try {
      /**
       * Check Whether Its NULL???
       */
      if (jsonObject != null) {
        /**
         * Check Length...
         */
        if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
          /**
           * Getting Array named "contacts" From MAIN Json Object
           */
          JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Keys.KEY_CONTACTS);

          /**
           * Check Length of Array...
           */


          int lenArray = array.length();
          if (lenArray > 0) {
            for (; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {

              /**
               * Creating Every time New Object
               * and
               * Adding into List
               */
              // 
              Service model = new Service();

              /**
               * Getting Inner Object from contacts array...
               * and
               * From that We will get Name of that Contact
               *
               */
              
              model.setName(name);

              /**
               * Adding name and phone concatenation in List...
               */
              ServicesActivity.getList().add(model);
            }
          }
        }
```